# Access MAMP's MySQL from Terminal

Tags: php, mysql, bash, terminal, mamp

I want to practice using SQL instead of phpMyAdmin.

How do I log into MAMP's MySQL from the terminal?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I'm assuming the version of MAMP you're using installs itself in /Applications/MAMP.  First make sure via the MAMP console that the Mysql server is on.  Then connect like this from command line:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uUsername -pPassword
```

Obviously replace Username and Password. BTW, there is no space between -u and the Username or -p and the Password.

Good Luck learning Mysql the old fashion way!

Comment: If you give the password in this way, other processes on the system can discover the password via `ps -ef` output. Best to leave the `-p` alone with no password, so you can give it via interactive terminal input, which can only be sniffed by processes with administrative privileges.

Comment: In general thats an excellent point, but I was assuming he was on a mac without any process reading trojans.  Still, it not a practice to get used to if you one day move to shared hosts

Comment: Thanks Ray! If I were on a shared host for my live website, what is the best way to enter the password?

Comment: Just enter -p without the password.   When it asks, what is your password, entering it at that point is safe.

Comment: @Donny P. dont forget to check my answer as correct if it resolves your question!  Thanks

Comment: This is for MAMP standard, but how to do this with MAMP PRO ?

Comment: In some versions, path is MAMP\bin\mysql\bin to run mysql queries.

Comment: This answer is still valid 8 years later, I have MAMP PRO and couldn't login via --host and --port, but this worked.

Answer (score 37):

If you just want to type:

```
mysql -u Username -p
```

**Update for macOS Big Sur** replace all `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` with `~/.zshrc` from the next commands.

Check first if you have a file named `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc` with the following command

```
ls -la ~/
```

If one of those files exist, edit that file. Else, create a new one with what ever editor you like (here I do it with nano and have a `~/.bash_profile` file)

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

insert following line

```
alias mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
```

Save the file and quit nano with `CTRL + X` and then type `Y` and `enter`

Then you need to type

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can use

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Good tip @caramba ! The only one thing more you need to get it work immediately is to execute: $ source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Or you can add the path to PATH in your .bash_profile and then you have access to run any executable in that directory from any place you are in terminal. e.g., export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:${PATH}". alias works too but only gives you access to that one command.

Answer (score 11):

Just simply create a symbolic link to the MAMP mysql.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql /usr/bin/mysql
```

Then you can easily call it from any directory like this:

```
mysql -uUsername -pPassword
```

Comment: Trying to link to `/usr/bin/mysql` says operation not permitted even with sudo. I instead linked it to `/usr/local/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 5):

I had to do a little modification, first go to the bin folder

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
```

then to run mysql file a had to execute

```
./mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD
```

The reason was that: [Running an executable in Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080835/running-an-executable-in-mac-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it on Windows type:

```
 c:/MAMP/bin/mysql/bin/mysql.exe -u username -p dbname < data.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not get any of the above working :/ I went to http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/using-mysql-command-line-with-mamp.html and it worked perfectly. Hope this helps.

Open a new *terminal window*, *copy and paste* the section below and *TADA*!

**/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot**

Answer (score 2):

This line works for me:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

then

```
  ./mysql -u root -p
```

Enter Your Password...