# Error #2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, mamp, mysql-error-2002

I'm running MAMP. 

It has been working fine up until yesterday. I haven't been able to find anything that helps so far. But here is my problem:

As the title states I'm receiving the following error:

> error #2002 *"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"*

which, I have noticed, seems to be a pretty common error when I search for it.

Anyway, When I cd to `tmp/mysql` and `ls -laxo` the only thing that shows up besides the `./` and `../` directories is `.dummy` (I have no idea what that is, but I have a hunch it's not the source of my problem).

That is where the `mysql.sock` file is suppose to be located. Does anyone know of  a way to fix this. Maybe I need to create the `mysql.sock` file but I wouldn't know what to put in it.

Comment: It's a been a while since I had this issue. But I believed I was able to fix this by running the command "killall mysqld" in the terminal. Hope that is somewhat helpful.

Comment: @BrandonBeeler: Thank you for coming back to post your fix. It worked for me when nothing else did :) You may want to post it as an answer and select it as the answer.

Answer (score 37):

**Test**

If you attempt to start MySQL using the full path it should work

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

---

**Fix**

If that works, then you can set it to work normally by running

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

---

**Resolution**

Now MySQL should work normally

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: what happens if the 'Test' fails? I still get the same error

Comment: You have another parameter that requires this answer to work... This doesn't like look a very valuable answer.

Comment: For those of you using XAMPP on OSX, @davidcondrey is still correct but the ```PATH``` differs slightly: ```ln -sf /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock``` and it should fire successfully.

Comment: u save my day :D tks!

Comment: This worked for me. Other solutions didn't.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is late, but if ever someone is searching this (as I was tonight, but I found the solution), here's what worked for me:

I opened MAMP and had to click "USE default Apache and MySQL ports". (80 and 3306 instead of 8888 and 8889). That seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Set MAMP MySQL port to 8889 worked for me.
You can do it under :
MAMP > Preferences > Ports.

Comment: Nope still recieving the same message after changing the port

Answer (score 5):

Silly solution... But in my case, I didnt start the mysql server. So, look that also!

Answer (score 1):

Mysql server has not started.

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather avoid changing ports through MAMP or options in my.cnf file, it might be useful to try forcing a TCP connection via the following on the command line:

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 8889 -u root`

Remembering to set the port is important if it's anything other than the mysql default of 3306.

The `-P` parameter allows you to set the port.

MAMP's default port is 8889, but you can verify what yours is set to easily via the MAMP WebStart page while MAMP is running:

http://localhost:8888/MAMP/

It'll look similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. When i start MAMP separately, then the problem gone. And issuing following command worked fine.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: This could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335403/access-mamps-mysql-from-terminal