# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when I typed "mysql"

Tags: mysql

I just installed mySQL and when I try to type mysql in my mac terminal I'm getting

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I tried searching for an answer but I'm still stuck. Also, I don't know if this is relevant or connected, but when I go to my preference panel to try to start mySQL it doesn't start. On some sites such as other stackoverflow pages, it says to try running "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe" but for me it just permission denied..

I tried to do ps -u mysql to check if it's running and it printed out and an address: usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local. So I assume it's running? Even though I can't physically press the button and enable it in the preference panel which is weird.

EDIT: I typed

> $ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
>
> Password:
>
> 130930 11:55:15 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/myname-mac.att.net.err'.
> 130930 11:55:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
> 130930 11:55:18 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/myname-mac.att.net.pid ended

why did it end right there?

Comment: Reads like your MySQL server isn't running. You'll need to get it started (see @ExplosionPills' comment)

Comment: I typed:

$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe. See above edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error #2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105796/error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-applications-ma)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error message for days and finally figured it out.

I had somehow gotten a my.cnf file on my computer from AMPS or possibly another MYSQL install (that I believed I had deleted).

But it turns out it was a hidden file in /etc/ that I had to manually delete. http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/

Finally, I installed MySQL with homebrew one more time –– and success! It works. Also of course this time I spot a message in the homebrew setup process that points out the problem I was having:

> A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a
>   Homebrew-built server starting up correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced a similar error. After trying all prescribed solutions like in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422630/1145905), noticed that it was a simple solution: first make sure the mysql daemon is running. For example, on a Homebrew installation (macOS), start mysql with: `brew services start mysql`