# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect php file with MySQl Server database in MacBook Air using Terminal. It shows me

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

I have seen many solution in Stack Overflow but I doesn't give the solution. I have tried by giving first parameter as both localhost and 127.0.0.1 but it gives me pic2 given below.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

My PHP code is below:

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect(':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'root', '1234');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" );
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, '');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Looks like permission issues.

Comment: `dtruss -f -t open php ....`. See what its looking for. Or are you using PHP7 and [mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) no longer exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error #2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105796/error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-applications-ma)

Comment: Sounds like the mysql service is not running.

Comment: No it is running at back...Still now I can't solve the problem