# MySQL server does not start with MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

**Environment**

- Mac OS Big Sur Ver 11.6
- MAMP Ver 6.5
- PHP Ver 7.4.21
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distribute 5.7.34

**Issue**

I was using MySQL on MAMP but now having errors after restarted my mac.

First, I got this error.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

And, the Stop-icon on MAMP is orange (I think it was usually green).

[image]

**What I did so far:**

1. Checked if the mysql.sock file exists.

```
$ ls /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/
```

2. Created mysql.sock file.

```
$ touch /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

3. Tried to start mysql again. (The Error message changed from (2) to (38).)

```
$ mysql -u root -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)
```

4. Tried to start mysql server.

```
$ mysql.server start
-bash: mysql.server: command not found
```

5. Checked if the path is set.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

6. Used the full path

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Looks like the server is not running

Comment: I think so too. That's why I used the command `$ mysql.server start`.Then I got the error `mysql.server: command not found`.   So I thought mysql doesn't installed but it does.

Comment: Could be a few issues (port, logs, path to mysql) Try the tests/solutions in these 2 links here, it might help out. [Error #2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105796/error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-applications-ma) OR [MAMP mysql server won't start. No mysql processes are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021564/mamp-mysql-server-wont-start-no-mysql-processes-are-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing (just moved to trash) and reinstalling MAMP.